# Community Builder suddenly shows only blank pages

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, community-builder, napili

I was trying to access the community builder in order to take out, and add some other lightning component from a page, when suddenly didn't show any data, only blank pages.

I am using a developer edition, and I tried with Mozilla and Chrome, too, to access some pages of the builder, but I keep getting the same problem.

Is there any limit hat I might have hit, or any internal problem that might have caused this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing againg my javascript controllers and helpers, I was able to fix the issue. It was related with a typo, in one of my controllers.

I had written `trye { .... }` instead of `try { .... }`.

Because the controllers, helpers, and renderers are encapsulated as JSON from aura, there is no syntax check available for us to signal these kind of errors, so we have to be careful on our caution.

Hope this helps!